# Transform object in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an onject like this;

```
[
    {
        "key1":1
    },
    {
        "key2":4
    }
]
```

I want to convert the above, to this;

```
{
    "key1":1,
    "key2":4
}
```

Whats the best approach?

Comment: `Object.assign({}, ...yourArray)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use for example `Array.reduce`:

```js
const input = [
    {
        "key1":1
    },
    {
        "key2":4
    }
];

const output = input.reduce((res, curr) => ({ ...res, ...curr }), {});

console.log(output);
```

or you can use simply `Object.assign()`:

```js
const input = [
    {
        "key1":1
    },
    {
        "key2":4
    }
];

const output = Object.assign({}, ...input);

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply merge two object
Below is the Code

```
var data=[
    {
        "key1":1
    },
    {
        "key2":4
    }
]


var finalObj = { ...data[0], ...data[1] }

console.log("finalObj............",finalObj)
```

**OR**

```
Object.assign({}, ...data)
```